# Difference between zero crossing and threshold

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, computer-science, edge-detection, vision

What is the difference between zero crossing and thresholding of an image apart from for zero crossing the threshold is zero? This is in the context of computer vision using a laplacian of Gaussian filter on an image. Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero crossings form thin lines. A function will typically cross the zero (change signs) at a point.

Thresholding at zero would give you the areas where the function (image) is positive.

Zero crossings of the Laplacian indicate the locations of edges in the image. This is a noise-sensitive way of edge detection, useful more as a theoretical concept than a practical approach. Canny detects edges by looking for local maxima in the derivatives. That is a much more practical approach, though theoretically it's the same concept as finding zero crossings of the 2nd derivative (which the Laplacian is).

Comment: So a zero crossing algorithm would move through the image and see where the sign changed from negative to positive or vice versa and would create a line in that location?

Comment: Yes, and you can do so with sub-pixel precision, in theory.